# getBoundingClientRect() doesnt work when scrolled far enough

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, getboundingclientrect

```
var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
```

It does it's job when i use it for facebook to detect the height of a post. Considering that `obj` is a node of that post. It works fine in my chrome extension when i can see the post. It  works when i scroll about 200px past it. But when I scroll far down, it doesnt work anymore.

```
rect.top = 0;
rect.bottom = 0;
```

Even though I'm sure that the dimensions are still higher than zero. What's happening?

the `computedStyle` about the display looks like this:

```
{"39":"display",
"display":"block",
}
```

Comment: If element is made invisible by `display:none`, `Chrome` won't set a proper `boundingClientRect` for it. Can you add the result of `getComputedStyle(obj)` to the question?

Comment: And is that what facebook does? Does it actively change the display of items?

Comment: Might be, really. You have the means to check it, actually. )

Comment: I tried to find out with the dev tools. But i didnt see any display changes. It would seem to me that the scrolling wouldnt go as subtle..

Comment: > Can you add the result of `getComputedStyle(obj)` to the question?

Comment: I added it. Took me a while to get it the right way ;). It says display Block in there

Comment: Ah, stupid me! I totally forgot about all the numeric properties - they just duplicate the named properties and won't add anything to the question, so you can remove it. Sorry. :(

Comment: I removed the nonsensical part

Comment: Ok, can you check the same thing (gbcr for that node) in Firefox?

Comment: I really cant atm. I do not have admin rights on this pc so i dont have it installed

Comment: No problem, just trying to show possible directions to check. In my case, `gbcr` worked fine - both in Chrome and Firefox - for all the items, even those well below the viewport's bottom.

Comment: Hmm.. that is very weird. It does not work wel for me here.. what could it be?

Comment: Could it be that getBoundingClientRect only returns something meaningfull for elements displayed on screen? (But I would like to see the specs for that.)